# Selenium Automation Framework

Tags: frameworks, selenium

I am user of Selenium RC with java for a quite long time. But till date I am not able to find the best framework for Selenium RC scripts. I would like to know the following details,
a) What are the different frameworks available for Selenium RC?
b) Which is the best one for Selenium RC with Java?

Help me with your answer, please also provide the supporting URL so that I can have some basic idea about the frameworks and chose the best one for my project.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We have been using OpKey, a framework on selenium build by CresTech. What we liked about it was out of box Object map and data map implementation..For us script maintenance was a issue we were struggling with.I would recommend OpKey

Answer (score 0):

We use [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html). In addition to providing a JUnit-type organization for system tests, it supports data driving and has scope for Continuous Integration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Page Object - [http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2015/02/page-object-model-for-selenium-webdriver.html]
2. Keyword Driven Framework - Keyword-based test design and test automation is formed on the idea that  the  discrete  functional  business  events  that  make  up  any application can be described using short text description (keywords). In this framework testers to develop test cases using Microsoft Excel using a list of keywords. When the test is executed, the framework 
   processes the Excel workbook and calls functions as sociated with the 
   keywords entered in the Excel spreadsheet. These keyword functions in 
   turn  perform  specific  actions  against  the  application  under  test 
   (AUT). 
   http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/keyword-driven-framework-example
3. Data Driven Framework 
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSiba01-R2M
4. Hybrid framework - Combination of Keyword and Data Driven framework